# Probability of two events hapening given their period and duration

Tags: probability

In a "pool" of X events with a period of T seconds and a duration of D seconds what is the probability of 2 events happening while one is ocuring?

For example, 600 people remove 1 coin from a bag every 30 seconds, each person takes 2 seconds to remove the coin from the bag, whats the probability of two or more peole taking one coin while the others are taking. Take into account that people are not syncronized in any way.

Comment: yeah, that seems reasonable

Comment: What has this got to do with periodic functions?

Comment: Is the action accurately periodic?  That is, if person A takes a coin out at $0.000$ seconds and ends the action at $2.000$ seconds, does he next take a coin at $30.000$ seconds?  In your example it is certain because each person is taking a coin $1/15$ of the time and you have $600$ people, so there are on average $40$ people taking a coin simultaneously.